# Proper way to remove .html extensions from URL and do a global redirect

Tags: magento2.3, url, product-urls, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I know how to remove.html extensions from URLs in Magneto 2.3, but I'm unsure what other steps I need to take to make sure I do everything properly.

I found that I should also create a global redirect in .htaccess but is there anything else I should take into consideration?

This is what I found to add in .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, and failing to achieve this with a rewrite rule, the following line of code worked:

> redirectMatch 301 ^(.*).html $1

This is quite useful to remove any URL extension and avoid broken links, hopefully, helps someone in the future